# Java w/ SQL Server Express 2008 - Index out of range exception

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, exception, sql-server-express

I created a stored procedure in a sql express 2008 and I'm getting the following error when calling the procedure from a Java method:

```
Index 36 is out of range.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:Index 36 is out of range.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:170)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setterGetParam(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:698)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setValue(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:707)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerCallableStatement.setString(SQLServerCallableStatement.java:1504)
    at fr.alti.ccm.middleware.Reporting.initReporting(Reporting.java:227)
    at fr.alti.ccm.middleware.Reporting.main(Reporting.java:396)
```

I cannot figure out where it is coming from... >_<

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
BS_C3

---

Here's some source code:

```
public ArrayList<ReportingTableMapping> initReporting(
        String division,
        String shop,
        String startDate,
        String endDate)
{
    ArrayList<ReportingTableMapping> rTable = new ArrayList<ReportingTableMapping>();

    ManagerDB db = new ManagerDB(); 
    CallableStatement callStmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
         callStmt = db.getConnexion().prepareCall("{call getInfoReporting(?,...,?)}");
         callStmt.setString("CODE_DIVISION", division);
         .
         .
         .
         callStmt.setString("cancelled", " ");

         rs = callStmt.executeQuery();
         while (rs.next())
         {
             ReportingTableMapping rtm = new ReportingTableMapping(
                     rs.getString("werks"), ... );

             rTable.add(rtm);
         }
         rs.close();
         callStmt.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
          e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
          if (rs != null)
                try { rs.close(); } catch (Exception e) { }
          if (callStmt != null)
                try { callStmt.close(); } catch (Exception e) { }
          if (db.getConnexion() != null)
                try { db.getConnexion().close(); } catch (Exception e) { }
    }   

    return rTable;
}
```

Comment: You're doing something with an array.  Need java code to be of any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't enough source code provided to be sure, but based on the stack trace, my bet is the number of ? placeholders and the number of parameters provided don't match. My guess is that you don't have enough placeholders. I'd suggest double-checking to make sure you have the right number of each.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the result of a known problem with Microsoft's SQLServer JDBC driver.  See this article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:

[Article ID: 919568: FIX: You may receive an error message when you use an escaped single quotation mark to set a parameter value for a prepared statement in the SQL Server 2005 JDBC Driver](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919568)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answers and time.

I had to change the stored procedure in the DB and when rewriting the code the error went away.

I guess that Sean Reilly was right =)

Regards.
BS_C3